# What is best way to avoid excessive nested components when using antd with React?

Tags: reactjs, antd

It looks like antd (https://ant.design) is generating an alarming amount of nesting to achieve its purpose. Maybe I'm wrong, but I feel there must be a better way.

For instance, I added colored text, like so:

```
<Text type="danger">Some words</Text>
```

At the DOM, it looks as expected:

```
<span class="ant-typography ant-typography-danger">Some words</span>
```

But when inspecting with react-tools, it looks bloated and doubled:

*("...>" = omitted attributes)*

```
<Text type="danger">
  <withConfigConsumer(Base)  ...>
    <Context.consumer>
      <Base ...>
        <LocalReceiver  ...>
          <ReactResizeObserver ...>
            <Typography ...>
              <Content.consumer>
                <span ...>
                  "Some words"
...

</Text>
<Context.consumer>
  <Base ...>
    <LocalReceiver  ...>
      <ReactResizeObserver ...>
        <Typography ...>
          <Content.consumer>
            <span ...>
              "Some words"
...

</Context.consumer>
```

Admittedly, I don't have enough experience with React. But isn't this excessive? Why is it doubled? And most of all: how can I use antd and avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid this when using `antd` as this is a React design pattern their team decided to use. Those wrapper components are HOCs - [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and their purpose is to apply/reuse some logic on their child components.

For example, in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/bb3c45f3bfb78c4069716c2b910c50c1e8371fe6/components/typography/index.tsx), you can clearly see that Text, Title and Paragraph are simply the same Typography component whose inner text gets [styled differently](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/bb3c45f3bfb78c4069716c2b910c50c1e8371fe6/components/typography/style/index.less) depending on if its passed a Text, Title or a Paragraph prop. This is to ensure extensibility: if they decide to create a Quote component, they will simply add a Quote entry to the Typography component, and define Quote styling that would possibly include italic text. The wrapper Typography component would then pass down this new italicized style to its child component - the inner text.

As for ReactResizeObserver, many Ant Design components require to have some kind of **onResize** event listener attached to themselves in order to be responsive - to change their size or structure based on the screen width. Instead of defining the same onResize listener and handler on every component that needs this functionality, they have created a single HOC that can wrap any component under the hood and allow it to be responsive.

You really shouldn't care about this, as this is common practice with many popular libraries like React Router or Redux.